# Community extensions not showing in Magento Connect Manager after 1.9x upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-connect

I have upgraded a magento website from 1.7x to 1.9x. I found many issues but one of them is pretty serious.
I have copied the app/code/community folder from the old to the latest version.
Now the problem is I cannot see those extension on my Magento Connect Manager. Neither I can install those extensions nor I can update those.

Please guide me as to what is the best way to get the extensions show up? What is the best way to upgrade infact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the files from the 1.7 Magento version to the 1.9 version will not make them appear in Magento Connect. Magento Connect has no reliable way of knowing that you copied it to `app/code/community`.

If I'm not mistaken, Magento uses the `var/package/moduleName.xml` files to tell Magento Connect which modules were downloaded and installed. This way, by checking the whole `var/package` folder, Magento Connect knows what was installed and has certain information about it such as the install date, module version, etc.

Try copying your `var/package` folder to the new installation, this might help eventually.

The best way to upgrade is copying the modules by hand, as Magento Connect still has some serious issues with dependencies and other stuff. I've tried using the manager multiple times but copying the folders into my IDE was by far the easiest and fastest.

Comment: Thanks for the details... I will check and post the updates here.

Comment: Thank you...this solution worked for me. Marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check file permission on Cache.cfg and connect.cfg inside downloader folder both files need to be writable

If this didn't work you can rebuild the cache.cfg if you have ssh access to the site:

```
./mage clear-cache
./mage mage-setup .
./mage sync --force
./mage sync-pear --force
```

Comment: Both the files has 0644 permission. I think both are writable. Do a need to change the permission to something else? Do I have to look somewhere else?

Comment: What about the owner and group for both files? did you review this?

Comment: Without the help of the hosting company is there any way to check that? While upgrading do we need to replace the downloader folder as well?

Comment: If you have sftp access use winscp to connect to your hostinh and you will be able to see and change the file owner and group

Comment: Need to set permission `chmod 700 ./mage`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the code changed in the makeRequest function after v1.9.0.1 in /downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Replace the Curl.php file for the one used in Magento version 1.9.0.1 or before.